# MYSQL Tables are being duplicated inside each other

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i dont know how to exactly describe it, but my MYSQL tables are losing their Primary Keys + Auto Increment and have data with 0 as an Id(prim+AI). After looking at these tables, the similar thing is that all of tables have duplicate entries of the same entries that they have inside of them.
As you can see in image 1.png, there are no Primary keys (there was a primary key when i first made the table and it was working the whole time). and as you can see in the 2nd image 2.png, entries are duplicated(dont know how) and there are records with 0 in the id.

[image: 1.png]
[image: 2.png]

---

Update 2: 
When this table was first created, the ID column was set as Prim+AI and it was working great. HOW DID IT LOSE THE PK+AI, i have no idea that is why am asking.

Also, in my project there are no codes(MYSQL) to add/remove PKs, Duplicate Tables etc.. the only codes i have are INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/SELECT.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: hmm, i don't think anyone can replicate or solve this issue easily, as the problem is: previously it was autoincrement on the pk, but now, it does not have autoincrement and pk... the big question, how come you lost the PK? is it not some application specific? (like the application that uses the table that generate the 'pk' -- or perhaps is there some trigger that automagically sets the 'pk').

Comment: i dont have any code that creates a PK, duplicate a table etc... all of the codes used in the project are simply, INSERT,Update,Delete.

Comment: Was your application all built by you? Or did you get some third part app and built your app from it? I'm asking because such behavior can happen when some initialization script is being run.

Comment: the app was built by me from scratch (php + mysql)

Comment: Can you show your create table statement(s), also is it only you connecting to the database? try to run from the mysql console `show processlist` and make sure you are the only one messing with it (remote possibility is you are being hacked).

Comment: i have used phpmyadmin to create my table didn't even use the console. also am checking the process list, multiple process all of them are "sleep"

Comment: There is a similar problem here https://superuser.com/questions/592140/phpmyadmin-removes-the-primary-key-for-mysql-table see if it helps you

Comment: i dont think that ive ever copied a table, but for the sake of the argument, what is the solution?

Comment: Well I would make a backup of the database, drop it and recreate it from scratch and try start inserting the data to see what happens

Comment: Also, maybe you didn't copied a table but this is a common problem for phpmyadmin. If you used it to create your table there is your problem, MAYBE.